# Delphi stack overflow due to a cycle in event handling

Tags: delphi, stack-overflow, delphi-6

I am working on the application  which has two listboxes.I load the two listboxes with values and when i keep on clicking the items from the list box i get the following error while debugging.

[image]

Running the exe causes the application to close.Sometimes i get the "Access Violation" message.

so what should I do to get rid of this error from my aaplication?

**EDIT**

..

The main form has timer that refresh all the controls
timer_RefreshCOntrol (intervali 1).

whenver the editBox_one is modified(value) 
this function is called

```
Procedure TStringSetting.SetValue (const AValue : String);
  Begin
   ...
    If FValueControl <> Nil then
    Begin
     FValueControl.OnChange := VoidNotifyEvent;
     FValueControl.Text := NewValue;
     FValueControl.OnChange := EditChange;        //<--here the stackoverflow error comes....
    end;
  end;




 Procedure EditChange (Sender: TObject);
   Begin
       Value := FValueControl.Text;
       If Not EditIsValid then FValueControl.Font.Color := clRed
       else If Dirty  then FValueControl.Font.Color := clBlue
                  else FValueControl.Font.Color := clWindowText;

       If @OldCustomEditChange <> Nil then OldCustomEditChange(Sender);
    end;`


   the EditChange (Sender: TObject); <--keeps geting called and the stackoverflow error comes
```

`EditChange` is assigned to the editbox on `FormCreate`

**EDIT2**

I am not the original developer.I just handled code sometimes back, major refactoring is not possible.

**edit 3**
The call stack value but what is the "???"
[image]

**EDIT 4**

after going through @Cosmin Prund and @david

i got the place where the infinity call start

```
   Procedure TFloatSetting.EditChange (Sender: TObject);
  Begin
    SkipNextOnChange := True;
  Inherited EditChange(Sender);
  IfValidThenStore(FValueControl.Text);
  Inherited EditChange(Sender);  {<-------This is where it start}
 end;


 Procedure TStringSetting.EditChange (Sender: TObject);
  Begin
   Value := FValueControl.Text;
   If Not EditIsValid then FValueControl.Font.Color := clRed
     else If Dirty  then FValueControl.Font.Color := clBlue
                  else FValueControl.Font.Color := clWindowText;

   If @OldCustomEditChange <> Nil then OldCustomEditChange(Sender); {<---this keeps calling  Procedure TFloatSetting.EditChange (Sender: TObject);}
 end;
```

Comment: It is completely impossible to say with this little information! Of course the Windows list boxes are not buggy. You need to show your specific code.

Comment: OK, first of all, using a timer (especially with an interval of 1 -- that's one thousand calls per second, which is even more than you can possibly get with a `TTimer`, and such a waste of CPU time) is horrible for this. Anyhow, most likely you have a procedure that is calling itself, or some other procedure that calls the first procedure. It should be easy enough to find that. Probably EditChange causes EditChange to be called, which causes EditChange to be called, and so on *ad infinitum*. To verify this, add `beep; sleep(1000)` to the beginning of EditChange. (Cont.)

Comment: (Cont.) If my hypothesis is correct, you should get one beep a second until you kill your program.

Comment: its a real time application and interval 1 is required .

Comment: Well, but even if you set the interval to 1 you won't get a thousand calls per second, because this is above the resolution of a Windows timer. You will not notice any change if you change the interval to 30.

Comment: yes,  the timer will refresh the application controls like painting and enable/disable buttons...yes waste of cpu time...but can this error be handled by try?

Comment: `try..exccept`, you mean? No, it cannot. You need to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: What happened when you added `beep; sleep(1000)` to the beginning of `EditChange`?

Comment: Stack Overflow errors are *usually* very easy to track: Build the application with all debug options enabled, when the error pops look at the Call Stack. You'll most likely see a loop of similar functions in there.

Comment: I was about to say exactly the same as Cosmin!!

Comment: You don't need to use a timer like that and if this app was designed properly then you likely would not have these problems. When someone like Andreas gives advice like that you should listen and view it as an opportunity to learn.

Comment: BeepSleep:  Awesome debug technique.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based in the posted call stack it's obvious why the error is happening: `TStringSetting.EditChange` triggers `TFloatSetting.EditChange` and that in turn triggers `TStringSetting.EditChange`. The loop goes on like this until all stack space is exhausted.

Here are some tips on why that might happen, and tips on how to debug and fix it:

- Maybe the controls involved trigger the `OnChange` event handler when the `Value` is changed progrmatically. If the two editors are supposed to display the same data in two formats and you're using the respective `OnChange` event handlers to keep them in sync, this might be the cause.
- Maybe you're directly calling one event handler from the other.

Ways to debug this:

- You should first try the breakpoint solution, as suggested by `paulsm4`. If the stack overflow happens every time one of the `OnChange` handlers is called, this solution would easily work.
- Comment-out the code for one of the event handlers. Run the program, the error should no longer appear. Un-comment the code in tiny (but logical) amounts, test and repeat. When the error shows up again, you know you fund the line that's causing the error. If you can't figure it out yourself, edit the question, add the code and mark the line that you just found out it's giving you trouble.

If the controls you're using are triggering the `OnChange` event handler when there value is changed programatically, you should make your event handlers non-reentrant: that would stop the infinite recursive loop for sure. I almost always assume controls trigger `OnChange` or equivalent events when properties are changed from code and always protect myself from re-entry using something like this:

```
// Somewhere in the private section of your form's class:
FProcessingEventHandler: Boolean;

// This goes in your event handler
procedure TYourForm.EventHandler(Sender:TObject);
begin
  if FProcessingEventHandler then Exit; // makes code non-reentrant
  FProcessingEventHandler := True;
  try
    // old code goes here ...
  finally FProcessingEventHandler := False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the above code worked and no stack overflow error now.

Answer (score 3):

You report a non-terminating recursive call sequence to `EditChange`. Looking at the code of `EditChange` there are two candidates for a recursive call:

1. `OldCustomEditChange` being equal to `EditChange`, or calling a function that in turn calls `EditChange`.
2. An event handler that responds to changes to `FValueControl.Font` by calling `EditChange`.

These are the only opportunities for the code in `EditChange` to call itself.

It is easy to see how both of these possibilities leads to the non-terminating recursive function call and eventually the stack overflow. Of the two candidates my bet is number 1. I would study carefully what happens when `OldCustomEditChange` is called.

To debug a stack overflow of this nature simply open the call stack window and look at the long sequence of calls. You will typically see a pattern with one function calling itself, possibly via one or more intermediate functions.

Answer (score 3):

Suggestions:

1. Set a breakpoint in EditChange and OldCustomEditChange to see who's calling them.  Each invocation.  Clearly, *only* EditChange should *ever* call OldCustomEditChange.
2. Look in your .dfm to make sure EditChange is only assigned to one event (not multiple events) and OldCustomEditChange isn't assigned at all.